# Class def not found from Kotlin code

Tags: google-app-engine, kotlin

I have Kotlin code:

```
         cluster.removeIf { t: SolutionElement -> t.timeStart < minimumDate } //Clusters.kt:66
```

Where cluster object is kotlin Mutable list. When I try to run this code on Google App Engine standard environment I got an error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/util/function/Predicate
    at com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-4a2a3dcd2b375db7(Request.java)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:820)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:375)
    at net.toolla.teamly.services.matcher.Clusters.removeExpired(Clusters.kt:66)
    at net.toolla.teamly.services.matcher.Clusters.pickMore(Clusters.kt:31)
    at net.toolla.teamly.services.matcher.BestMatchWorker.getSolutionElements(BestMatchWorker.java:232)
    at net.toolla.teamly.services.matcher.BestMatchWorker.match(BestMatchWorker.java:116)
    at net.toolla.teamly.services.matcher.MatcherService.doPost(MatcherService.java:37)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:454)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:461)
    at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:297)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:320)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:312)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:458)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.util.function.Predicate
    at com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-4a2a3dcd2b375db7(Request.java)
```

In build.gradle for this module, I had:

```
compileKotlin{
    kotlinOptions{
        jvmTarget = 1.6
    }
}
```

Without that parameter error was:

```
Uncaught exception from servlet
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/toolla/teamly/services/matcher/Clusters$removeExpired$1
```

Where "removeExpired" is name of the function which contains the above line.

I changed the code above to some less convenient and older syntax, but it would be great to know how to use some more up to date techniques.

Comment: try to set ``sourceCompatibility = 1.6`` in gradle. `Predicate` should not be used in Java <1.8. Or would you like to compile to for JRE8?

Comment: yes, it's true - but the code is in Kotlin and it compiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class `java.util.function.Predicate` was introduced in Java 8. So run it with 8. About th

```
...
 * @since 1.8
 */
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Predicate<T> {
```

About that error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   net/toolla/teamly/services/matcher/Clusters$removeExpired$1

Ensure that you have that class on your `classpath`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `removeIf`, which is a method from JDK 8 and is therefore not supported on JDK 6, you can use the [removeAll method](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/remove-all.html) from the Kotlin standard library, which is supported on all JDK versions.